# How to keep the original google page when building a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension which changes the background image of the original google page. But everything that I have tried it just removes everything and starts from scratch.​ Is there a way that I could keep the original google page and add my background images

I have already tried to use the google source code to replicate it but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your extension configured to be able to inject scripts into google.com domains, all you need to do is get the body and change the "background-image" style. 
I tried the following code in an injected script and it seems to do the trick:

```
let googleBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
if(googleBody) {
  googleBody.style.backgroundImage = `url("https://images.gog.com/60c724a052275a049d857d53957dc38e9347742f52372bb956d992b43efa8fb5_product_card_v2_mobile_slider_639.jpg")`
}
```

Also keep in mind that you can't inject scripts into the newTab view so if you're trying to inject scripts there they'll probably fail.